# Create a class library consisting of many sub-classes

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, oop

This is a follow-up to my previous question [Stop my "Utility" from giving errors between different architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381821/stop-my-utility-from-giving-errors-between-different-architectures), suppose I am trying to create a class library that looks something like this:

```
- Class Utility (Parent class)
     ... Utility functions and methods
         (EG: Public Sub Sub1() )

  - Class Utility_Web
       ... Functions and methods only related to Web / Web-Controls
         (EG: Public Sub Web_Sub1() )

  - Class Utility_WinForms
       ... Functions and methods only related to Winforms / WinForm-Controls
         (EG: Public Sub WinForm_Sub1() )
```

Now, what I would like to be able to do is to just add the `Utility` dll as a reference to any of my projects and be able to access the functions and methods from ALL 3 of these classes by simply typing in, for example:

```
Utility.Sub1
Utility.WebSub1
Utility.WinFormSub1
```

In other words, **not having to type**:

```
Utility.Utility_Web.Websub1
```

And making it so that the end-programmer doesn't need to know the internal structure of this utility, they can reference all it's methods / functions with just the `Utility.` nomenclature.

How would I go about doing that? Is this where `NameSpaces` come into effect? `Inheritance`? `Partial Classes`? `Modules` rather than classes?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to have the WinForm implementation and the Web implementation both use the same method names, and then have the code using it just not know which implementation is actually getting called?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, @Steven - No, each class has its own modules and functions and no names are repeated between the classes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any reason for these methods to be in separate classes if they are going to be accessed using the same class name.

If you want to split the code across many source files for organizational purposes, you can use [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx).

Comment: Note that for `partial classes` they must be in the same namespace.

Comment: As long as all of the partial classes are in the same project/assembly.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: The OP is "trying to create a class library" and refers to "the `Utility` dll". That sounds like one assembly.

Comment: It is one assembly - And thanks, @Jon, I actually updated my question with that as something I was considering... This is all still fairly confusing to me (best programming practices), but that does make perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an excellent instance where you'd want to use partial classes, all using the same Utility namespace.  That would allow you to access the methods with Utility.WebSub1 and reduce a step.

Comment: Thanks, @David, seems like this is where I'm bieng pointed by everyone. +1 as a big thank you for answering, I'm just going to award the question to Jon since he answered first. THANKS!!!!

Comment: More than fair :).  I was just typing away and never bothered to expand to see the current answers.  Glad to hear it helped!

Answer (score 1):

A class named `Utility` is a bad class from the start. What is its utility? What does it help you do?  How many other people are going to name classes Utility?

Name your classes for what they do, associate them in the namespaces where they make logical and functional sense.

Let's say that you are making a set of static methods that help out with a class that represents a `Month`.  Why not put the methods into `Month`?  If you're writing methods to transform data from one representation to another, name it that way (ie, `MonthDataTranslation`).

Don't worry about typing on the part of your clients or your client code.  Intellisense and the C# using statement mitigate that a great deal and given the choice between a badly named, nebulous Utility class and a long, well-named class, I will pick the latter every single time.

Comment: Thanks, @plinth, I very much appreciate the advice and am actually programming like that, I just used the `Utility` example since it seemed the easiest way to explain my question.